# how to use str.startswith for multiple columns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, startswith

I have a dataframe that looks like this: 
[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc8DL.png)

I used this to filter for users who's id's begin with b, c, e, f, 5 and was able to successfully execute this.

```
df[df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))]
```

I now want to do the same for columns userA and userB, and tried running this unsuccessfully:

```
df[[df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))] and [df.userB.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Return rows for which *both* `userA` and `userB` start with (`'b'`, `'c'`, etc.)?

Comment: If you want to filter such that both users begin with these letters, use `&` instead of `and` : `df[(df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))) &(df.userB.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5')))]`

Comment: that worked! thanks, rafael. How do I get it to return the opposite, ie, all users that DONT start with b c e f 5?

Comment: Use the `~` operator before the mask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use `and` since in Python this will return the *first* operand that has truthiness `False` (or in case there is no such operand in an `and` chain, the last element).

You can however use the `&` and `|` operators as a logical *and* and *or* respectively to apply multiple conditions.

So for your case, you probably want to use:

```
df[
    df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5')) &
    df.userB.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))
]
```

(this gives the "rows" of the dataframe `df` for which *both* `userA` and `userB` start with a character in `('b','c','e','f','5')`); or

```
df[
    df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5')) |
    df.userB.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))
]
```

(this gives the "rows" of the dataframe `df` for which *at least* `userA` or `userB` start with a character in `('b','c','e','f','5')`)

For more information, see the documentation on [*Boolean indexing* in the *pandas* documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: This is good, but how to do for arbitrary number of startswith patterns on a single column? E.g. I want to know if my column starts with "ABC" or "XYZ".