# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', and 'g'

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

```
# Create a new column 'new_label' based on the 'label' column
selected_data['new_label'] = selected_data['label'].apply(lambda a,b,c,d,e,f,g: 'DDoS' if a.startswith('DDoS') else 'Mirai' if b.startswith('Mirai') else 'Recon' if c.startswith('Recon' or 'Vulnerability') else 'Spoofing' if d.startswith('DNS' or 'MITM') 
  else 'Benign' if e.startswith('Benign') else 'Web' if f.startswith('Browser' or 'Backdoor' or 'XSS' or 'Uploading' or 'Sql' or 'Command') else 'BruteForce' if g.startswith('Dictionary') else 'other', meta=('new_label', 'object'))

# Compute the result
selected_data = selected_data.compute()
selected_data
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-cdf5d20f0f25> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 
      5 # Compute the result
----> 6 selected_data = selected_data.compute()
      7 selected_data
```

I'm facing the error mentioned in the title. I am trying to classify different types of attack into subclasses. I'm working on the CIC IDS IOT 2023 dataset. The above error is occuring when the code is trying to `compute()` the data.

Comment: What contain the label column?

Comment: And what are a,b,c,d,e,f and g parametres  in the lambda function

Comment: label column contains different types of attacks which are mentioned in the `.startwith()` function. And a to g are parameters which are needed to act as a lambda function

Comment: Why not one argument , just a ?

Comment: How many labels do you have in old label?

Comment: I tried that, and now I'm re-running the colab notebook and trying to solve this by using the global function. It has 34 unique labels

Comment: Python is not going to unpack the tuple into the 7 lambda arguments, it's going to pass all of them as a single tuple into the first arg, so it's not `b` but `a[1]` and so on. It used to unpack tuples into args in Python 2, but not Python 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892989/how-can-i-simulate-2-xs-tuple-unpacking-for-lambda-parameters-using-3-x and https://peps.python.org/pep-3113/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lambda` get only one parametre each time , is the one you need use (not 6):

```py
selected_data['new_label'] = selected_data['label'].apply(
   lambda label: 'DDoS' if label.startswith('DDoS')
   else 'Recon' if label.startswith(('Recon', 'Vulnerability'))
   else 'Other'
)
```

Also I corrected the condition with multiple values , see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458085/how-to-use-str-startswith-for-multiple-columns)